# what is environment variable EBSDIR?

Tags: unix

i am getting an error "Unable to determine installation location. Please set the environment variable 'EBSDIR' to the installation directory."

can anyone tell me what is environment variable EBSDIR and what does it used for? which installation path it is asking for?

thanks

Comment: We'd like to help. But we've no idea what software you're attempting to install. You should get more useful information if you ask the software vendor this question.

Answer (score 1):

It is the installation directory for the McAfee E-Business Server. The default location would be `/usr/local/ebs`.

Try:

```
locate McAfeeEBSGUI.jar
```